# mysql drupal 6 Query issue

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to query an entry that has the lowest number value and then update the number value to value +1 in the database as follows:

```
$ras = db_query("SELECT name,number FROM {people} ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1"); 
$raw = db_fetch_array($ras);
$com_name = $raw['name'];
$count = $raw['number']+1;
db_query("UPDATE {people} (number) SET ('%d') WHERE name='%s'", $count, $com_name);
```

I get an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `SET` clause is wrong.

Try this:

```
db_query("UPDATE {people} SET number = '%d' WHERE name='%s'", $count, $com_name);
```

or this, (if your `number` column is `INT` type:

```
db_query("UPDATE {people} SET number = %d WHERE name='%s'", $count, $com_name);
```

**NOTICE** the removed quotes?

Comment: This works, thanks! a few minutes before i can accept answer.

Comment: Does it matter if %d is or is not placed in quotes?

Comment: @ingrid No. It doesn't matter.